# difference between a.equals(b) and array.equals(a,b)

Tags: java, arrays

I have run this small program:

```
String[] a = {"a","b"};
String[] b = {"a","b"};


    if (a.equals(b)){
        System.out.println("woop");
    }else{
        System.out.println("doh!");
    }


    if (Arrays.equals(a, b)){
        System.out.println("woop");
    }else{
        System.out.println("doh!");
    }
```

The output of the program is "doh! woop".

I get the difference between  the == and .equals but what is the difference between these equals operations?

Comment: Did you glance at the documentation ?

Comment: It's sad that pasting from the obvious documentation looks like the thing to do here for so many users, even some with more than 1k...

Comment: I expect that object-compare method with name 'equal' will use '.equals()' for comparation, and not '=='. This is realy weird behavior.

Comment: @degr It does, but it uses `Object#equals()`, which is just a `==` check.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

`equals` compares array instances, `Arrays.equals` compares array elements.

**Full Explanation**

Arrays do not implement `equals`. As a result, they hand the method off to `Object` which is implemented as follows.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return (this == obj);
}
```

Thus, `equals` on an array is the same as `==`.

`Arrays.equals` has the following description. It compares the elements of the array.

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of longs are equal to one another.  Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal.  In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.  Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)`...

> returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)). In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

In short, all your `String`s are compared through `equals`.

See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29).

`Object.equals`, which is invoked when comparing two arrays with the `array1.equals(array2)` idiom, compares the reference, just like `==`.

See source for `java.lang.Object`:

```
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    return this == o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `a.equals(b)` will use == under the hood, since arrays don't override the `Object.equals()` method. You use this to test for **instance equality** between arrays.

So in your case, `a.equals(b)` will return false, since the two arrays are different instances.

Instead, `Arrays.equals()` actually compares what's **inside** the arrays. If the arrays contain the same values, then `Arrays.equals()` returns true. You use this to test for **semantic equality** between arrays.

Answer (score 1):

With arrays, `a.equals(b)` is the same as `a == b`.  This is checking if the two array instances are the same.  `Arrays.equals(a,b)` takes the time to compare each element of both arrays and checks if the *elements* are equal, which is different than checking if the containers themselves are equal.

A quick analogy:  Let's say *a* and *b* are buckets.  Asking if the two buckets are the same is **not** the same as asking if what is in the buckets is the same.